# Why in dreamweaver does the split and design view not render your css layouts like the live view?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

In dreamweaver cs6 the live view works fine for displaying the divs.  But when it comes to the design and split view.  They both display the divs wrong and it is nothing like what is shown on the live view or in a browser.  Is there a reason for that?  How do I fix it?

Comment: The reason is that the dreamweaver editor is not a very good rendering engine.

Comment: Im looking at alternatives.  What about eclipse and the html plugin?  Or do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to stop using wysiwyg editors :-)  they are fine for the very simple tasks, but write really poor HTML when you're trying to do something complicated. The html plugin for eclipse week do the same as the live view

Answer (score 0):

You fix it by not using dreamweaver, and just test your site in a real browser.

It's bad enough that modern browsers have slightly different interpretations of HTML/CSS/JS.  I wouldn't want to further complicate things by viewing/testing a website in something that isn't a web browser.

If you want a more useful answer, it would help us if you posted screenshots of the site in dreamweaver vs in a browser.

Comment: Good suggestion, not an answer.